# Margin in popup menu (qt3)

Tags: c++, qt3

[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/6218/menuk.jpg](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/6218/menuk.jpg)

Is there any method to get rid of the huge margin on the right side? It appears to be constant, because adding some text to the menu items doesn't change its width at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QPopupMenu is inherited from QWidget. So try function `setMaximumWidth()` or try to use `adjustSize()` after adding  all items in popup menu.